# Xcode project does not recognise changes in custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have created two projects in Xcode:

- Framework. It just has one public class and one public method
- Xcode project.

I have drag and dropped my framework into project. After that, framework was automatically added into General tab of the target and Build Phases's `Link Binary With Libraries`. I just needed to changed to `Embed & Sign` in General's `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`.

Then I went to my ViewController, added:

```
import MyCustom_Framework
```

After that, I have created an instance of my class and called it's only method in viewDidLoad, and **it worked fine**:

```
let customClass = MyCustom_Class()
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    customClass.someMethod(text: "Something") //someMethod is a method name
}
```

Then, I went back to my Framework, and changed the method name from `someMethod` to `anotherMethod`.

Xcode does not succeed to recognise that change. I have tried to delete derived data, clean and build the framework again, removing framework from the project and re-adding it again. Nothing helped.

Comment: When you say "two projects" do you literally mean two separate Xcode project files? Instead of doing it this way, I would use a single project file with multiple targets. Then make your framework target a dependency of your app target. This way, any changes to the framework will cause it to be rebuilt on the next build of the app.

Comment: yes, two separate Xcode project files. I understand what you mean. But there must be some way to make this work if they are completely separated? I separated them because I thought that it would be easier to handle when I make a Xcframework based on this framework later and publish it on SPM/Cocoapods. Does that make sense?

Comment: also, what is the point of creating a framework inside Xcode project, with multiple targets? for example, I want to create some framework on my machine with some useful methods which I will be able to use in all of my projects.

Comment: Okay, separate Xcode projects should still work, just a little more complicated. Have you tried dragging and dropping the whole Xcode project into your app project? You app project should be able to see the targets of your framework project if you do that.